# Store data in a correct format after scraping in Python, post processing the csv data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, post-processing

Scraping is done now i have to postprocess the data stored in a csv file,

```
import pandas as pd
import uuid
def postprocess():
    clean= ['Home','Shri','Smt','Dr','Mr','Mrs','Ms','Contact','Facebook','account','photo','Of','Biography','Email','Address','Roles','To','Read','more','Blog','Vacancies','Advertisement','Advertise','Holding','Second','Estimates','Fax','Find','Close','Links','Key','Figures','Stats','Statistics','Household','Full','name','Parks','Open','Menu','Languages','Opinion','Education','Address','Latest','Activity','NA','Father','Husband']
    banned = ['january','february','march','april','may','june','july','september','october','november','december','monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday']
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv("result.csv",names=['Prefix','Name','Designation','Nation','Created_date_time'],encoding= 'unicode_escape')
    except:
        return
    df = df.applymap(str)
    df.replace(to_replace = 'nan', value = '', inplace = True)

    print("Postprocessing...")

    df.dropna(subset=['Name'],inplace=True)
    df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'], keep='first',inplace=True)
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    for count,_ in enumerate(df['Name']):
        if  len(df['Name'][count])<4:
            df.drop(count,axis=0,inplace=True)
            continue
    
        if  df['Prefix'][count].isnumeric() or len(df['Prefix'][count])>15:
            df.at[count, 'Prefix'] = ''
        if 'Home' in df['Prefix'][count]:
            df.at[count, 'Prefix'] = df['Name'][count].replace('Home','')
        for item in df['Name'][count].split(' '):
            if len(item)<2:
                df.at[count, 'Name'] = df['Name'][count].replace(item,'')
        for word in clean:
            if word in item:
                new_val = df['Name'][count].replace(word,'').strip()
                df.at[count, 'Name'] = new_val
        for ban in banned:
            if ban in item.lower():
                df.drop(count,axis=0,inplace=True)
                break
        else:
            continue
        break
                 

    df.dropna(subset=['Name'],inplace=True)
    df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'], keep='first',inplace=True)
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    uuids = []
    for _ in range(len(df)):
        uuids.append(uuid.uuid4().hex)
    df.insert(0, '_id', uuids)

    print("Postprocessing complete. Database contains {} rows".format(len(df)))

    df.to_csv("result.csv",index=False)
```

I am not getting the require result
What i am getting is:

```
id          Prefix    Name                                  Designation    Nation   Created_date_time  
random id          font size present(some random words)       India      this is correct
```

I am not getting prefix, name is not correct, in place of designation country is showing and in place of nation date and time is showing

what i actually want is:

```
id          Prefix    Name         Designation  Nation  Created_date_time
random id    Mr       Ankur Singh   Analyst      India    date and time
```

Is there any suggestion for this... what things i need to correct or what can i do

[image: Output required in csv]

Comment: Would be better if you could share sample csv with expected output.

Comment: @MayankPorwal i have shared sample csv